# Allow admin user all access in access_control in security.yml

Tags: symfony, admin, access-control, symfony-2.7

noob question, I'm working in Symfony 2.8 and I want to grant all access to the role ROLE_ADMIN in access control, is there a way to do this without writing 'ROLE_ADMIN' in every rule over access_control?

What I´m trying to avoid in my security.yml, is going from this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/application, roles: ROLE_STUDENT }
    - { path: ^/keyword, roles: ROLE_MENTOR }
    - { path: ^/department, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/requirement, roles: ROLE_MENTOR}
```

To this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/application, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_STUDENT ]}
    - { path: ^/keyword, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MENTOR ]}
    - { path: ^/department, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/requirement, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MENTOR ]}
```

in a most larger file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add role hierarchy:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_STUDENT, ROLE_MENTOR]
```

That way if you have `ROLE_ADMIN`, you have also `ROLE_STUDENT` and `ROLE_MENTOR`.